# ESP8266 micropython terminal not reponding?

Tags: esp8266, micropython

I bought [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B081PX9YFV) boards and was trying to install micropython and then launch the REPL, but when I would start the putty session the chip would send the proper stuff but I could not type anything. I tried:
reinstalling both the 2MB+ firmware and the 1MB,
adding `fm -dio` to the install,
reinstall drivers for my computer.
Any other ideas?

Comment: I just tried while using Thonny's esptool addon, and it worked! Anyone know why? I don't really like having so many IDEs for everything, and want to delete it.

Comment: Does putty have any sort of [flow control](https://documentation.help/PuTTY/config-serial-flow.html) enabled by default?

Comment: yea, that was it. Putty was on XON/XOFF by default once I changed it to none it worked fine. Thank You!